# How to install CLISP in Redhat Linux

Tags: linux, lisp, common-lisp, redhat, clisp

I was searching, how to install CLISP (http://www.clisp.org) in RedHat Linux. In the CLISP web site Fedora installation link is broken.

`yum install clisp` doesn't work even though `sudo apt-get install clisp` in Ubuntu.

Anyone there, installed CLISP in RedHat Linux?

Comment: *doesn't work*... What error do you get? The package is called `clisp` so it *should* work. If you decide to install `sbcl` as @Sylwester suggest, I'd also suggest installing `rlwrap` and calling with `rlwrap sbcl`, which will allow your shell arrow keys, etc, work properly. `clisp` doesn't need `rlwrap` for them to work.

Comment: lurker: Do I have to add any repo before install clisp?

Comment: It's been a long while since I installed it (Fedora Core 17), but I don't recall adding any special repos to install clisp. What error are you getting? As you point out, the Fedora package link at clisp.org is broken, which doesn't bode well. Why not use `sbcl`?

Comment: `No package clisp available. Error: Nothing to do` This is the error message I get. Do you think the code wrote for CLISP will build with SBCL without a change?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a CL-implementation you can use `sbcl` which will run standard CL-code as good as clisp.

If you want clisp download the tarball and follow the instructions in ihe INSTALL file.

There is [a thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21511) in the CentOS forums about a yum installation alternative, but it might not work on recent releases.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed it on Fedora 18. Repo:

http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/c/

It has been moved to 'archives.fedoraproject.org' because it's old. So if you have an old fedora you might have to add this repo to your yum repos.

Answer (score 2):

You can build from source, I just wanted to learn a little bit about lisp and this allowed me to get setup and get started:

You can find releases here: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/clisp/release/

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/clisp/release/2.49/clisp-2.49.tar.gz 
tar xvfz clisp-2.49.tar.gz
cd clisp-2.49 
./configure --prefix=$HOME --ignore-absence-of-libsigsegv 
cd ./src 
make install
```